# How to add image to HTML in Pycharm?

Tags: html, flask, pycharm

I am developing a Flask application in Pycharm, where one of the routes should return HTML page with an image in it:
`<img src="C:\Users\IlkinU\PycharmProjects\build_det\static\images\output.png"/>`
However, the image does not display in browser and the following error message appears in console:

> Cannot resolve file 'C:\Users\IlkinU\PycharmProjects\build_det\static\images\output.png'

Tag works perfectly fine in Visual Studio code, but not in Pycharm. After searching, I found out I have to use something similar to `<img src="{%static "images/yourimage.jpg" %}"`, however couldn't use it. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: you probably should be using a relative path not an absolute one

Comment: same error persists

Comment: What path do you specify to relative image, and what is your project root?

Comment: my project root is "C:\Users\IlkinU\PycharmProjects\build_det", build_det being the root folder. In this case relative path would be "<img src="static/images/output.png">".